# Boost program_options Can I create shorthand options with more than one character?

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently migrating an old application with some weird command-line arguments.
While using Boost program_options, I try to keep some of those arguments from the old version of the application, to assure the compatibility of some user scripts.

My problem is that I couldn't find a way to add shorthand options with two or more characters.

For example, if I add:

```
("testOption,to", "This is just a test-option")
```

to the options_description, I only get -t as the shorthand for --testOption.

Is there some way to use longer shorthand options?

Comment: @ForEveR Thanks, while searching for this I didn't find this post. It definitely answers my question. What should I do with my question should I just delete it. Or add an answer with the link?

Comment: I'd add an answer with a link, your question has a better title!